# Looping in Python if user did not input a value from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm coming up with a simple piece of code to play a game of rock, paper, stick and stones using `input` and `random` functions. In the code below, I'm trying to figure out how to loop `my_input` if the user enters an integer that is not a valid choice.

```
import random
import time


def my_input():

    #validinput = False
    #while not validinput:
    while True:
        try:
            mychoice = int(input("Your choice? (1. paper, 2. scissor, 3. stick or 4. stone) "))

        except ValueError:
            print('You did not enter a valid input. Enter again.')
            continue

        else:
            if mychoice == 1:
                return 'paper'
            elif mychoice == 2:
                return 'scissor'
            elif mychoice == 3:
                return 'stick'
            elif mychoice == 4:
                return 'stone'
            else:
                return 'invalid choice'


def randomized():
    choice = ['paper', 'scissor', 'stick', 'stone']
    return random.choice(choice)


def game():
    user_continue = True
    while user_continue:
        myinput = my_input()
        print('YOU: ' + str(myinput))
        randomval = randomized()
        time.sleep(1)
        print('COMPUTER: ' + randomval)
        won = 'You won!'
        lost = 'Sorry, you lost.'
        draw = "It's a draw."
        if myinput == 'paper' and randomval == 'scissor':
            time.sleep(1)
            print(lost)
        elif myinput == 'scissor' and randomval == 'paper':
            time.sleep(1)
            print(won)
        elif myinput == 'paper' and randomval == 'stick':
            time.sleep(1)
            print(lost)
        elif myinput == 'stick' and randomval == 'paper':
            time.sleep(1)
            print(won)
        elif myinput == 'paper' and randomval == 'stone':
            time.sleep(1)
            print(won)
        elif myinput == 'stone' and randomval == 'paper':
            time.sleep(1)
            print(lost)
        elif myinput == 'scissor' and randomval == 'stick':
            time.sleep(1)
            print(lost)
        elif myinput == 'stick' and randomval == 'scissor':
            time.sleep(1)
            print(won)
        elif myinput == 'scissor' and randomval == 'stone':
            time.sleep(1)
            print(lost)
        elif myinput == 'stick' and randomval == 'stone':
            time.sleep(1)
            print(lost)
        elif myinput == 'stone' and randomval == 'stick':
            time.sleep(1)
            print(won)
        else:
            print(draw)

        #continue looping until user says no
        user_yn = str.upper(input('Do you want to continue? Press Enter  or type any value other than N '))
        if user_yn != 'N':
            print('continuing...')
            continue
        else:
            break
game()
```

Any other suggestion to make this code shorter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Post your code on https://codereview.stackexchange.com to get suggestions for improvements. Make sure that the code is complete and works correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there.

**Short Answer:**
Replace `return 'invalid choice'` with `print('invalid choice')` This works.

**Explination:**
After comparing the entered input value with the desired values of 1 to 4, you are returning from the infinite loop with return statement. If the value is the desired one, this works, but even for invalid values you are exiting with `return 'invalid value'`. So instead of returning it, print the same message to the user, and as it is in infinite while loop the menu prints again prompting the user to input his choice again. This won't exit the loop until the user enters the desired value between 1 to 4.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a dictionary for mychoice:

mychoice = {1:"paper", 2:"scissors", 3:"stick"}

that would condense some. also would help with your randomized function

Comment: That way when you loop, you can use the dict mychoice[1] == paper, etc. and then you can say perhaps p1 is human and p2 is computer. Then check if mychoice == mydict[1] and randomval == mydict[2]...winner == p2... and go from there. That way you don't need the full if elif.. just an opinion

Comment: Thank you for the idea although i honestly don't know how to do that.